# Embedded C (FreeRTOS)

Tags: c, rtos

Trying to create a reaction timer. Timer rand counts down from 10. LED is red and turns green when the user has pressed the switch. The user has to press either sw2 or sw3 when prompted has a 5 second gap to press switch. Once switch is pressed, the time is recorded and printed to putty. Game then resets and user can play again. 
I'm current stuck trying to implement the LED and rand timer, could anyone help:

```
#include "freeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "semphr.h"
#include "queue.h"
#include "timers.h"
#include "event_groups.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include "board.h"
#include "peripherals.h"
#include "pin_mux.h"
#include "clock_config.h"
#include "MK64F12.h"
#include "fsl_debug_console.h"
#include "fsl_UART.h"
#include "fsl_device_registers.h"

/* TODO: insert other definitions and declarations here. */
QueueHandle_t switchQueue = NULL;
TaskHandle_t displayHandle = NULL, UARTHandle =NULL, LED_TaskHandle = NULL;
static void displayTask(void * pvParameters);
static void LED_Task(void *pvParameters);

static EventGroupHandle_t SW_Group = NULL;

#define SW2_bit 1<<0
#define SW3_bit 1<<1
/*
 * @brief   Application entry point.
 */
void BOARD_SW2_IRQ_HANDLER(){
    static int8_t count = 0;
    static uint32_t buffer[5];
    BaseType_t xHigherPriorityTaskWoken;
    PORT_ClearPinsInterruptFlags(BOARD_SW2_PORT, 1<<BOARD_SW2_GPIO_PIN);
    buffer[count] = xTaskGetTickCountFromISR()*(1000/configTICK_RATE_HZ);
    printf("\n\rSW2 pressed at %d", buffer[count]);
    /* if(GPIO_PinRead(BOARD_INITPINS_SW2_GPIO,BOARD_INITPINS_SW2_PIN)== 0)
        {
            PRINTF("Switch pressed!.\r\n");
            xEventGroupSetBits(SW_Group, SW2_bit);
            while(GPIO_PinRead(BOARD_INITPINS_SW2_GPIO,BOARD_INITPINS_SW2_PIN) == 0){}
            //vTaskSuspend(NULL);
            if(++count==5){
                    count=0;
                    xHigherPriorityTaskWoken = pdFALSE;
                    //send copy of buffer to queue
                    xQueueSendFromISR(switchQueue, buffer, &xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
                    portYIELD_FROM_ISR(xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
                }
        }*/
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(100));
    }

int main(void) {


    /* Init board hardware. */
    BOARD_InitBootPins();
    BOARD_InitBootClocks();
    BOARD_InitBootPeripherals();
    /* Init FSL debug console. */
    BOARD_InitDebugConsole();
    BOARD_InitLEDsPins();



    //configure sw2 interrupt
    NVIC_SetPriority(BOARD_SW2_IRQ, 10);
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(BOARD_SW2_IRQ);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(BOARD_SW2_IRQ);

    SW_Group = xEventGroupCreate();

    switchQueue = xQueueCreate(5,20); //5 item queue of 20 bytes per item
    if(xTaskCreate(displayTask, "Time Display", 100, NULL, 3, &displayHandle)== pdFALSE)
    {
        printf("UART task not created\n\r");
        while(1)
            ;
    }
    if (xTaskCreate(LED_Task, "LED_Task", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE + 10, NULL, 4, &LED_TaskHandle) != pdPASS)
        {
            PRINTF("LED_Task creation failed!.\r\n");
            while (1)
                ;
        }

    vTaskStartScheduler();

    volatile static int i = 0;
    /* Enter an infinite loop, just incrementing a counter. */
    while(1){
        i++;
    }
    return 0 ;
}

static void displayTask(void * pvParameters){
    uint32_t rxBuffer[5];
    printf("Starting display task\n\r");
    while(1){
        if(xQueueReceive(switchQueue, &rxBuffer, portMAX_DELAY) == pdTRUE){
            //print data
            printf("\n\n\rData Received from Queue:");
            int x;
            for(x=0;x<5;x++){
                printf("\n\rData %d: %d",x,rxBuffer[x]);
            }
            vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(100));
        }
    }
}

void LED_Task(void *pvParameters)
{
    EventBits_t event_bits;
    for (;;) //no conditions in the for loop, will run forever
        {
            event_bits = xEventGroupWaitBits(SW_Group, SW2_bit | SW3_bit, pdTRUE, pdFALSE, portMAX_DELAY);
            if(event_bits & SW2_bit){
                PRINTF("Event bit set, RED LED Toggled!.\r\n");
                LED_RED_TOGGLE();
            }
            else if(event_bits & SW3_bit){
                PRINTF("Event bit set, GREEN LED Toggled!.\r\n");
                LED_GREEN_TOGGLE();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag it `C++`?

Comment: it's saying i only tagged c and rtos?

Comment: I edited out the C++ tag

Comment: As the question hasn't been answered for about 5 months now, I suggest that it is refined (edited) to a more specific aspect (generation of random data OR setting leds OR dealing with timer), and that it is given a more specific name. Plese don't be frustrated if you haven't received an answer by now. By formulating [a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you increase the probability to get a suitable answer considerably.